# how to display Link Action selected Properties in Actions Tab in iText5

Tags: java, itext

I need to display selected link Properties action when user click on **Action** tabs of an existing pdf using iText5

[image]

**look like below screen**
[image]

Comment: iText does not have a graphical user interface, so it is impossible to *"display selected link Properties action when user click on Action tabs of an existing pdf using iText5"*.

Comment: I need programmatically solution to select action which is selected inside edit button

Comment: In that case you should ask the company that created the GUI in question to provide information what they require in a PDF for their GUI to show those information. (Those GUIs are not standardized, so it is completely up to the respective implementer of the GUI which information they present how.)